# Teamcity prompts for credentials when using nuget 3.4.4

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-package-restore, teamcity-9.0

We recently updated the Nuget.exe version on our teamcity server to nuget 3.4.4. We use an authenticated feed, and now suddenly our builds are failing. We use the "Nuget Feed Credentials" feature in Teamcity, and with nuget 2.8.0 this works perfectly. Once we switch a build config to use 3.4.4 for package restore, it fails with the following:

```
Restoring NuGet package MyPackage.1.0.0-DEV004.
[16:04:05][restore] Please provide credentials for: https://nugetserver.company.com/api
[16:04:06][restore] UserName:   GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MyPackage';,Version='1.0.0-DEV004')
[16:04:06][restore]   NotFound https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MyPackage';,Version='1.0.0-DEV004') 602ms
[16:04:07][restore]   GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='MyPackage';
[16:04:07][restore]   OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='MyPackage'; 162ms
```

Is there anything I can do about this? Is nuget 3 not compatible with the "authenticated feed" build feature in teamcity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to the [TeamCity 10.0.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/) where issue [TW-44438](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44438) was addressed.